# How do I pass the job name into a github action's input?

Tags: github, github-actions

```yaml
jobs:
  my-name:
    name: "My Name"
    ...
    steps:
      - name: Slack Notification
        uses: my-action
        with:
          slack-msg: ${{ jobs.${{ env.GITHUB_JOB }}.name }}
```

I want that slack-msg to evaluate to "My Name". I'm using my-action in multiple jobs, and I always want to pass in the job name, but I don't know how to do that. When I tried the above, the job literally didn't run and I don't know how to troubleshoot why: the github workflow log for `my-name` literally doesn't exist.

How do I pass job-name into an input parameter?

Comment: Would it be an option to use the `job_id` (in your car `my-name`) instead of the `job name`? Because the `job_id` is available in the Github Context using `${{ github.job }}` when the `job name` is not...

Comment: @GuiFalourd Sorry, but no.

Comment: @DanielKaplan were you able to find a way to get the "My Name" value?

Comment: @MikalaiDaronin No, I used sorin's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nested expression are not supported you can use a trick like below to obtaint the matrix job name.

```yaml
jobs:
  test:
    env:
      # to expose matrix job name to steps, which is not possible with expansions
      JOB_NAME: ${{ matrix.name || format('{0} ({1})', matrix.tox-target, matrix.os) }}
    name: ${{ matrix.name || format('{0} ({1})', matrix.tox-target, matrix.os) }}
```

Note that you cannot really access the matrix name, but you can ensure you save the same name into an environment variable and use that.

Comment: Sorry it's been too long. Can you link to the relevant documentation so I can learn what this `matrix` thing is? Thanks

Comment: Doc: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategymatrix  ;  More explanation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs