# How to get GitHub Actions matrix job name within job?

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to upload logs separately for each failing job in a matrix. Each set of logs needs to have a name based on the job matrix, otherwise they clobber each other and I can't tell which job the resulting artifact came from.

I tried printing all the contexts:

```
name: My workflow
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize]
jobs:
  my-job:
    name: OS ${{ matrix.os }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os:
          - ubuntu-18.04
          - ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - run: echo "${{ toJSON(github) }}"
      - run: echo "${{ toJSON(env) }}"
      - run: echo "${{ toJSON(job) }}"
      - run: echo "${{ toJSON(steps) }}"
      - run: echo "${{ toJSON(runner) }}"
      - run: echo "${{ toJSON(secrets) }}"
      - run: echo "${{ toJSON(strategy) }}"
      - run: echo "${{ toJSON(matrix) }}"
      - run: echo "${{ toJSON(needs) }}"
      - run: echo "${{ toJSON(inputs) }}"
```

None of these contain the job name as displayed when running the workflow.

Answer (score 5):

It's currently not possible to extract the `jobs.<job_id>.name` directly from the Github Context.

There is no native way (yet?) to extract the `job_name` from the runner context, only the `job_id` (using `${{ github.job }}`).

Therefore, the answer to your (title) question is that **it's not possible** (yet), using or not a matrix, without a workaround.

*Note: You can find some other threads about the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611978/get-current-job-name-in-github-actions-workflow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69636799/how-do-i-pass-the-job-name-into-a-github-actions-input)*

---

In your case, as you use the `matrix` to define the job name, it is actually possible to set the job name the same way in the workflow as env variable (if you wish), doing this workaround:

```yaml
jobs:
  my-job:
    name: OS ${{ matrix.os }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os:
          - ubuntu-18.04
          - ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{ github.job }} # Will only return the job_id: "my-job"
      - run: |
          JOB_NAME="OS ${{ matrix.os }}"
          echo $JOB_NAME
          echo "JOB_NAME=$JOB_NAME" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Print JOB_NAME
        run: |
          echo "JOB NAME:" ${{ env.JOB_NAME }}
```

*I tested it [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/2030781555) if you want to have a look.*

That way, the `JOB_NAME` env variable can be used in any step (if you want to use it as a log file name), or even be saved as an output for use in sequencial jobs.

When creating your log files, you could add a `timestamp` or the workflow `run_id` (`${{ github.run_id }}`) to the `JOB_NAME` as log file name, to identify which workflow produced it, when uploading it.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, but it doesn't really answer the question. I already know how to use variables; I'm trying to avoid duplicating `jobs.*.name` within the job itself.

Comment: Why would it duplicate the `jobs.*.name` here? You're using a matrix for the job name, so it will always be unique in each job execution. If you upload the logs using it, it will always be unique for this workflow run. Now, it you want to make them unique running the workflow various time as well, wouldn't adding a timestamp to the log name file (together with the JOB NAME variable) resolve the problem? Regarding the answer, what I say still stand, you currently can't get the `job_name` from the runner context, only the `job_id`. It's not possible (with or without matrix) without a workaround.

Comment: Instead of using a `timestamp`, using the workflow `run_id` (`${{ github.run_id}}`) could even be better, as it's also unique for each run. This composed key would be perfect in your case.

Answer (score 3):

One possible workaround I discovered recently is to use an expression for the matrix, rather than naming each component separately:

```
jobs:
  test:
    name: Run ${{ join(matrix.*, ' - ') }} - ${{ github.event_name }}
```